# Merging two DataFrames with date and other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, data-manipulation

I am trying to merge two DataFrame on Date and column called IDV. Here is my first DataFrame

`df1`

| Date | IDV | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | Var1 | 100 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var2 | 500 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var3 | 600 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var4 | 10 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var5 | 10 |

`df2`

| Date | IDV | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2019 | Var2 | 110 |
| 01/01/2019 | Var3 | 510 |
| 01/01/2019 | Var1 | 300 |
| 01/01/2019 | Var5 | 20 |
| 01/01/2019 | Var4 | 20 |

my desired output would be

| Date | IDV | Values | Last_Year_Values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | Var1 | 100 | 300 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var2 | 500 | 110 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var3 | 600 | 510 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var4 | 10 | 20 |
| 01/01/2020 | Var5 | 10 | 20 |

I tried `pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on ='date',right_on ='IDV', how = 'left')`

Comment: Date column is string or datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateOffset` if `Date` is already `datetime64`:

```
cols = ['Date', 'IDV', 'Values']
out = df1.merge(df2[cols].assign(Date=df2['Date']+pd.DateOffset(years=1)), 
                on=['Date', 'IDV'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_last_year'))
print(out)

# Output
        Date   IDV  Values  Values_last_year
0 2020-01-01  Var1     100               300
1 2020-01-01  Var2     500               110
2 2020-01-01  Var3     600               510
3 2020-01-01  Var4      10                20
4 2020-01-01  Var5      10                20
```

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Date': [pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')],
              'IDV': ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4', 'Var5'],
              'Values': [100, 500, 600, 10, 10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'Date': [pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01'),
               pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')],
              'IDV': ['Var2', 'Var3', 'Var1', 'Var5', 'Var4'],
              'Values': [110, 510, 300, 20, 20]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Comment: It is doing for whole Data Frame I want this only for one column from last year - values as last_year_values. I have other colums say full name, and couple of more this do add last to every column to every column _last_year_values. I just need one column that us values in last year

Comment: If you just want `Value` column, subset your dataframe with `df2[['Date', 'IDV', 'Value']].assign(...)`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Another error:  `"['Values'] not in index"`

Comment: It works for your sample. Why `Values` is not in your columns?

Comment: I have 'Values' in my both Data Frame, Not sure why its like that

Comment: Maybe you have a leading or trailing whitespace in the column names? What is the output of `print(df2.columns)`?

Comment: `'level_0', 'index','place','date','zone','IDV','Values'`

Comment: I think you are solved your problem using @mozway's answer.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: silly mistake I made. I was using the DataFrame has last_Year_Values but  i was operating on Values.  Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a string type, a simple method would be to change the year in df2:

```
pd.merge(df1,
         df2.assign(Date=df2['Date'].str.replace('2019', '2020')),
         on=['Date', 'IDV'],
         how='left', suffixes=('', '_last_year'))
```

or for a more generic method (works with any year):

```
pd.merge(df1,
         df2.assign(Date=df2['Date'].str.replace(r'\d+$', lambda m: str(int(m.group(0))+1), regex=True)),
         on=['Date', 'IDV'],
         how='left', suffixes=('', '_last_year'))
```

output:

```
         Date   IDV  Values  Values_last_year
0  01/01/2020  Var1     100               300
1  01/01/2020  Var2     500               110
2  01/01/2020  Var3     600               510
3  01/01/2020  Var4      10                20
4  01/01/2020  Var5      10                20
```

Comment: I am getting an error:
`Can only use .str accessor with string values! `

Comment: Then use the alternative suggested by @Corralien, or convert to string.